# Pthread id and sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I need to do the following:
Create a thread that creates 10 threads in a row. 
Each thread just prints it's ID and sleeps for n seconds, where n is the serial number of current thread.
But, I can't get passing arguments right, when I run my code it seems like the thread is just sleeping.. Some help, please?

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# define N 10

void* printID (void *i)
{
int* p=(int*) i;
sleep(p);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* th (void* unused)
{
int sec,i;
sec=1;
i=1;

while(i<=10){
pthread_t pid1;
pthread_create (&pid1, NULL, &printID, (void *)&i);
pthread_join(pid1,NULL);
printf("Thread ID je: %d \n",(int) pid1);

i=i+1;
}
}

int main(){

pthread_t pid;

pthread_create (&pid, NULL, &th, NULL);
pthread_join(pid,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable your compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument passing is fine. But you are not passing the value to `sleep`.

It should be

```
sleep(*p);
```

`p` points the address of `i` (from the function `th()`). You need to dereference the pointer to get the value.

Comment: Thanks :D It works
Problem now is, it just writes same id 10 times.. :s

Comment: Pthreads is probably reusing the pid as you only create a new thread after the previous one exited. If you want to create and run them all at the same time, you need to make quite some changes to your code for it to work properly. May be, ask a new question.

Comment: I think it's fine then.. Thank you, one more time.